# Is the 'how should I format' sidebar guidance as relevant as it could be?

Tags: discussion, markdown, help

This is the current how to format sidebar:

[image]

Could this be updated in any way? For example, I think the html link suggestion should go.

Comment: They're not exactly *out of date*... it's about preference I think.

Comment: @ᔕᖺᘎᕊ perhaps, I'm not sure how to phrase this question

Comment: neither am I really.... not sure what you're asking (I didn't -1 btw)

Comment: Are you saying the Markdown examples don't work? Or that you want to impose your preference across the board even though Markdown allows some variation on how to format?

Comment: I'm pretty sure 'years' sufficiently describes the last time that was touched. While it's not incorrect or inappropriate guidance to give folks, it .. is a bit out of date and in need of attention.

Answer (score 4):

I love markdown. After using it extensively on SE, I now do *most* of my writing using it. I get annoyed when I stop and reflect upon the fact that Google docs *still* doesn't support it.

Prior to coming here, I had no idea that it really existed. I'd heard of it, and just figured it was something like bbcode or something else. In my defense, that *was* in 2008.

But, not *everyone* knows how it works, or even what it is, so advertising that a limited subset of HTML is supported is a good thing. Kinda like if you were a scientist and went to a conference, if all else failed, Latin might work.

What's interesting about this is, despite that - we *still* get 'probed' by spammers for bbcode support around a thousand times a day. Stupid robots.

I am not in love with how we *show* the formatting guidance, but I'd like to keep the same information there in any change we might make.

Comment: So is this a "maybe the presentation will change"? I'm especially interested in how the link html / markdown is shown - it's quite confusing, and also maybe showing the top bar buttons next to the item could be useful?

Comment: @Tim We're taking a hard look at the `questions/ask` page now. You can count it as a maybe, more like a probably, but we're looking months ahead with that.

Comment: Okay, nice to know, I'll think 6-8 weeks :)

Comment: ....... roughly.